# Undeclared sprite error using pointers

Tags: c, pointers

My sprite won't draw from the while loop even when declared within a function.

```
int main( void ) {
//other functions
    while(1) {
        update_hero(&hero_sprite);      
    }
}

void setup_hero() {

Sprite hero_sprite;
Sprite * hero_sprite_pointer = &hero_sprite;
byte hero_bitmap [] = {
    BYTE( 10100000 ),
    BYTE( 11100000 ),
    BYTE( 10100000 )
};
const int width = 3;
const int height = 3;
}

void update_hero(Sprite * hero_sprite) {
    draw_sprite(&hero_sprite);
    refresh();
}
```

Is there a reason why?

Comment: You  can see that it's a terribly bad idea to have that as a public variable?

Comment: I've moved the sprite declaration into the setup_hero function. Still getting the same error.

Comment: please copy and paste the exact error message, I suspect you have a typo, a subtle one like `sprite` and `sptite`, it would be hard to note it.

Comment: zombiedash2.c:31: error: 'hero_sprite' undeclared (first use in this function)
zombiedash2.c:31: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
zombiedash2.c:31: error: for each function it appears in.)

Answer (score 2):

This is your code, indented and annotated:

```
int main(void)
{
    //other functions
    while (1) {
        update_hero(&hero_sprite);
```

The line above must fail to compile; there is no variable `hero_sprite` in scope to take the address of.  Or, if there is, lots of critical information has been omitted from the question.

```
    }
}

void setup_hero(void)
{
    Sprite hero_sprite;
    Sprite *hero_sprite_pointer = &hero_sprite;
    byte hero_bitmap [] = {
        BYTE( 10100000 ),
        BYTE( 11100000 ),
        BYTE( 10100000 )
    };
    const int width = 3;
    const int height = 3;
}
```

This whole function is equivalent to:

```
void setup_hero(void)
{
}
```

None of the values mentioned in the function is visible outside the function.  There is nothing useful done inside the function.  A good compiler will reduce the code to the no-op I showed.

```
void update_hero(Sprite *hero_sprite)
{
    draw_sprite(&hero_sprite);
    refresh();
}
```

It seems improbable that `draw_sprite()` takes a `Sprite **` value as its argument.  It is also noticeable that `update_hero()` is not declared before it is used; that neither `draw_sprite()` nor `refresh()` is declared before it is used; and that `setup_hero()` is not used (and this reinforces that it serves no purpose in the code that is presented).

Make sure you're compiling your code with options that require functions to be declared (or defined) before they're used, and pay heed to your compiler's warnings.  Remember: at this stage in your career, your compiler knows a lot more about C than you do.

Answer (score 0):

in your update_hero function you are passed in a pointer to a sprite.

Instead of this:

```
draw_sprite(&hero_sprite);
```

you will want this:

```
draw_sprite(hero_sprite);
```

or otherwise you will be calling draw_sprite on a pointer to a pointer to a sprite

Comment: That is not the reason, it's that `&hero_sprite != hero_sprite`, the first is the address of the pointer itself, which is not what the function is expecting.

Comment: Well also his argument variable is the same name as his global, so that is creating some confusion, at least for me, with what he is trying to pass around.